# ASPnet web Form Navigation

Tags: asp.net

I want to redirect a new tab and to get focus of the new window when a button is clicked.. I can create a new window, but can't get its focus even thourh, I tried the following code
Window.focus(); How to do this?

My Code:
function new_window(url)
 {

```
 //Open a Window in New tab
 var popupwin = null;
 popupwin = window.open(url);
 popupwin.focus();
 self.focus();
 //window.focus();
```

}

Comment: Could you share some code? That would make it a lot easier to identify the problem.

Comment: Remove self.focus() and check what happens

Comment: IE... It is working in Firefox... But, not in Google Chrome and IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `focus()` method of a form element. This brings *mostly* the window to front. `window.focus()` might implemented different by different browsers.

Do you have html input elements on you popup win?
Try calling focus() on one of the html input elements. This will place the cursor into the element to assist the user start typing there.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better not to do this. These are browser preferences and don't try to override those. It may fail due to user settings.

Remove

```
self.focus();
```